# Populate NULL Values based on Array Formula

Tags: sql, sql-server

New user, so apologies in advance for bad formatting.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is be able to populate the `staff_hours` column where it equals NULL with the one value that IS NOT NULL. As you can see from the screenshot, there will only be one person who staffs an open `cl_hole_staffing_no` and as a result will have a `start_dt` (with time) and `end_dt` (with time) along with `staff_hours`. 16 people were offered a shift, and the person in row 15 accepted it is what is going on here.

The ideal output would be the `staff_hours` column is populated with the amount of time of the one person who ended up taking the open job, so 24.00 in this example. How can I write a formula to do this? I was thinking something like an array function in Excel, but am not sure how to do that in SQL.

[image: SQL staff screenshot]

Comment: If you are sure it's only one filled person per `cl_hole_staffing_no`, then it will probably be `max(staff_hours) over(partition by cl_hole_staffing_no)`.

Comment: It is not clear what you want as a result.

Answer (score -1):

Your explanation is a bit confusing about what you are really trying to achieve. However I think that what you really want is just to populate the **staff_hours** column, which can be achieved with the following:

```
UPDATE
  your_table_name
SET
  staff_hours = 24
WHERE
  staff_hours is NULL;
```

---

EDIT

I get it now. You want to operate with the two dates and extract the amount of hours between them. Since you are in sql-server you can actually define a *Computed Column* in which you can use the values from other columns to compute the value you want.

You will need to create your table again. (The example below contains only the necessary attributes for it to work)

```
CREATE TABLE your_table_name
(   id INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL  
  , staff_start_dt DATETIME
  , staff_end_dt DATETIME  
  , staff_hours AS DATEDIFF(hh, staff_start_dt , staff_end_dt)  
);
```

Now every time you insert a record on the table with both **staff_start_dt** and **staff_end_dt**, the column **staff_hours** will automatically compute the number of hours between the two dates.

Answer (score -2):

[pre]
Code (vb):

## A      B     C

1    10     X     X
2    11     A     Y
3    12     Y     Z
4    13     B
5    14     B
6    15     Z
[/pre]

Assuming that the rows in Col A is Named "datarange"

And your criteria is in C1:C3

The following formula will return an array {10,12,15}

=SMALL(COUNTIF(C1:C3,B1:B6)*datarange, ROW(INDEX(A:A,SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(C1:C3,B1:B6)=0))+1):INDEX(A:A,ROWS(datarange))))

COUNTIF(C1:C3,B1:B6)*datarange returns {10;0;12;0;0;15}

The segment ROW(INDEX(....):INDEX(...)) returns {4;5;6}, indicating the number of non-zero values.

The SMALL() function then returns the 4th smallest, 5th smallest and 6th smallest values.

One disadvantage with this approach is that you get a sorted sub-list. Perhaps that would work for you.